# Compiling C/C++ application using SDL in OS X, linking problem

Tags: macos, g++, sdl, compilation, x86-64

I'm trying to compile a C/C++ program that uses SDL on a OS X 10.6.8 but I'm having some errors on the linking stage, the code compiles but fails to like due to some missing symbols. The error is:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"_CFBundleGetMainBundle", referenced from: 
  -[SDLMain setupWorkingDirectory:] in libSDLmain.a(SDLMain.o)
  _main in libSDLmain.a(SDLMain.o)
"_CFBundleCopyBundleURL", referenced from:
  -[SDLMain setupWorkingDirectory:] in libSDLmain.a(SDLMain.o)
"_CFURLCreateCopyDeletingLastPathComponent", referenced from:
  -[SDLMain setupWorkingDirectory:] in libSDLmain.a(SDLMain.o)
"_CFURLGetFileSystemRepresentation", referenced from:
  -[SDLMain setupWorkingDirectory:] in libSDLmain.a(SDLMain.o)
"_CFRelease", referenced from:
  -[SDLMain setupWorkingDirectory:] in libSDLmain.a(SDLMain.o)

...

"_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSAutoreleasePool", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in libSDLmain.a(SDLMain.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [dist/linwarrior] Error 1
```

I checked with the `file` command and the libraries are either x86_64 only or universal with both i386 and x86_64 versions.

Is there a way for me to determine what exactly is causing this error? A way to check the libs that are being included or any way to help debug the problem?

I don't know if it helps but this is what my Makefile creates, I removed file names to make it short, and the KNT flag is just something I'm using for preprocessor conditions:

```
/opt/local/bin/g++-mp-4.5 -DKNT=1 -Wp,-M,-MP,-MT,-MF, -std=c++0x -Wall -I source -O1 -funroll-loops -c -o
```

Thanks.

Comment: Solved it.

I was being misled by the error message, thinking the problem was related to one thing when in fact it was just some libraries that were missing. I needed to include Cocoa and OpenGL frameworks, and do this before the SDLmain library.

Comment: Wasn't sure how to include the frameworks. [This link was helpful](http://content.gpwiki.org/index.php/SDL:Tutorials:Setup#Mac_OS_X:_GCC_.26_G.2B.2B) but the short answer is your linker flags should look like `-lSDLmain -lSDL -framework Cocoa`

Comment: @Cuadue The link leads to a page that somewhat archived the original content, but otherwise it has been bought by for some resort ad stuff and the bottom of the page is filled with ad links.